# Skip Smoothing step for ROC Curve with AUC = 1 in multiple iterations run

Tags: r, proc, smoothing, roc, auc

We have around 200 Prediction tables like shown below for 200 Iterations, some of them have `AUC = 1`, and rest of them `AUC < 1`

Smoothing of roc curve with `AUC = 1` gives errors, where as Smoothing of ROC Curve with `AUC < 1` gives no error.

**Question:**
How to skip Smoothing of ROC Curves with `AUC = 1`, and smooth the rest of the remaining curves with `AUC < 1` in R when we have 200 Prediction tables.

**Tried work:**
Have tried `ifelse()` based on `AUC < 1` but it runs for few iterations correctly, but then fails everytime. Please help on the same.

---

**Prediction table where AUC < 1**

Gives no error when smoothing.

```
 library(pROC)
 roc_tab <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 pred   A   B obs    Resample rowIndex
    A 1.0 0.0   A Fold01.Rep1        1
    A 0.9 0.1   B Fold01.Rep1       20
    B 0.4 0.6   B Fold01.Rep1       23
    A 0.6 0.4   A Fold02.Rep1        6
    B 0.3 0.7   B Fold02.Rep1       17
    A 0.7 0.3   B Fold02.Rep1       27
    A 0.9 0.1   A Fold03.Rep1        2
    B 0.1 0.9   A Fold03.Rep1        3
    B 0.2 0.8   B Fold03.Rep1       19
    A 0.9 0.1   B Fold03.Rep1       29
 ")

 train_roc <- roc(roc_tab$obs, roc_tab$A, positive = "A", na.rm = TRUE, 
 direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
 train_roc
 #
 # Call:
 # roc.default(response = roc_tab$obs, predictor = roc_tab$A, na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE, positive = "A")
 # 
 # Data: roc_tab$A in 4 controls (roc_tab$obs A) > 6 cases (roc_tab$obs B).
 # Area under the curve: 0.5833

 train_roc_smooth <- roc(roc_tab$obs, roc_tab$A, positive = "A", smooth = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
 train_roc_smooth
 #
 # Call:
 # roc.default(response = roc_tab$obs, predictor = roc_tab$A, na.rm = TRUE,     direction = ">", smooth = TRUE, auc = TRUE, positive = "A")
 # 
 # Data: roc_tab$A in 4 controls (roc_tab$obs A) > 6 cases (roc_tab$obs B).
 # Smoothing: binormal 
 # Area under the curve: 0.6093
```

---

**Prediction table where AUC = 1**

Gives error when we try to smooth as you can see at the end.

```
 # roc_tab1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 #    pred   A   B obs    Resample rowIndex
 # 1     A 1.0 0.0   A Fold01.Rep1        1
 # 2     A 1.0 0.0   A Fold01.Rep1       20
 # 3     B 0.0 1.0   B Fold01.Rep1       23
 # 4     A 1.0 0.0   A Fold02.Rep1        6
 # 5     B 0.0 1.0   B Fold02.Rep1       17
 # 6     B 0.0 1.0   B Fold02.Rep1       27
 # 7     A 1.0 0.0   A Fold03.Rep1        2
 # 8     A 1.0 0.0   A Fold03.Rep1        3
 # 9     B 0.0 1.0   B Fold03.Rep1       19
 # 10    B 0.0 1.0   B Fold03.Rep1       29
 ")

 train_roc <- roc(roc_tab1$obs, roc_tab1$A, positive = "A", na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
 train_roc
 #
 # Call:
 # roc.default(response = roc_tab1$obs, predictor = roc_tab1$A, na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE, positive = "A")
 #
 # Data: roc_tab1$A in 5 controls (roc_tab1$obs A) > 5 cases (roc_tab1$obs B).
 # Area under the curve: 1

 train_roc_smooth <- roc(roc_tab1$obs, roc_tab1$A, positive = "A", smooth = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
 #
 # Error in smooth.roc.binormal(roc, n) : 
 #   ROC curve not smoothable (not enough points).
```

---

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the smoothed ROC curve to look like with AUC=1? How smooth or sharp do you want the corner to be? In other words, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which returns smoothed or not-smoothed results depending on the AUC value. From a programming perspective, the code below will do the job for you. However, from a statistical point of view, I would question an AUC value of 1.

```
get_auc <- function(df) {
  result <- roc(df$obs, df$A, positive = "A", na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
  # check if smoothing needed or not
  if(result$auc == 1) {
    return(1) # if you are only interested in AUC
    # return(result) # if you are intersted in the entire result list returned by roc
  } else {
    smoothed_result <- roc(df$obs, df$A, positive = "A", smooth = T, na.rm = TRUE, direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
    return(as.numeric(smoothed_result$auc)) # if you are only interested in AUC
    # return(smoothed_result) # if you are intersted in the entire result list returned by roc
  }
}

get_auc(roc_tab)
# [1] 0.6093235
get_auc(roc_tab1)
# [1] 1

## if you want to loop through 200 data frames that you have

# create a list of data frames
dfs <- list(roc_tab, roc_tab1)
# to store AUC values, form a variable with the same length of your list
n <- length(dfs)
AUC <- replicate(n, NA)

# loop throuh the list and extract respective AUC values
for(i in 1:n) {
  AUC[i] <- get_roc(dfs[[i]])
}

# list of AUC values
AUC
# [1] 0.6093235 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The smoothing is done after the calculation of the roc, then a solution is to make the adjustment in two steps, instead of using the parameter of the function `roc`.

```
train_roc <- roc(roc_tab$obs, roc_tab$A, positive = "A", na.rm = TRUE, 
                 direction = ">", auc = TRUE)
train_roc_smooth <- if(train_roc$auc < 1) smooth(train_roc) else train_roc
```

Comment: The second line would be more readable as `train_roc_smooth <- if(train_roc$auc < 1) smooth(train_roc) else train_roc`.

Comment: This solution works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. 
I have a list of 10 roc objects and one of them has value 0.96 so it should smooth but it does not, that has 10 samples. Any restriction on no. of samples to have enough points to smooth the roc object?

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem is the number of observations, but there is not enough variability. If you have less than 5 observations in any of the categories of your objective variable (A and B) you should not smooth.

Comment: Thank you for keeping your point. Could you please tell on what basis you are saying that less than 5 observations in any of the category of objective variable should not be smoothed? Do you have any resource or help link that could help us and where we can read about what you said..?

Comment: 5 records in the minimum is the minimum sample size required to get some statistical conclusion, I would not be able to give you references of this, this is something universal. If you want to calculate the necessary sample size in a strictly (assuming an error), you will need much larger sample sizes. You can look at this [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5121784/) to have more detail.